# reStructuredText Hyperlink References a local pdf file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

```
nginx_pdf_
.. _nginx_pdf: Mastering Nginx.pdf
```

Mastering Nginx.pdf is a local pdf file in the some directory with the rst file. I want if click the Hyperlink , Browser would open the pdf file, but this can not work. how can I make this happen

Comment: If you just replace the space in the title of pdf file it works: `.. _nginx_pdf: Mastering_Nginx.pdf` (also rename the original file)

Comment: change name can not work, because I select Separate source and build directories when using sphinx-quickstart. When I make html , the pdf file not copy to the build directory automatically. just get a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sphinx

Just make the `_downloads` folder in your project, and put the file there. Then call it from the rst file:

```
:download:`_downloads/Mastering Nginx.pdf`
```

and it should be working.

## docutils

Replace the space in the name of the pdf file with an underscore after this it works:

```
nginx_pdf_

.. _nginx_pdf: Mastering_Nginx.pdf
```

Build it with:

```
rst2html test.rst > test.html
```